# Using system("command") in Linux

Tags: c, linux, web-crawler, wget

Is it recommended to call shell commands from a C program in C using **system()** ?

I want to develop a web crawler in C and want to use **wget** to fetch content from a URL ?
Should I do it using **system(" wget ...")**?

Comment: You could use `libcurl` a library of functions for fetching URLs.

Comment: No, you should use `libcurl` instead.

Comment: Why and why not using system() ? :(

Comment: Because using `system` reduces portability by over 9000!

Comment: Because it will be quicker and more efficient.  Once you've got the page(s) using `wget` you'll need to open them and parse them anyway, which is most of the problem.

Comment: 9000 what? you left out the unit.

Comment: @trojanfoe I can use htmltidy to do the parsing ?

Comment: Why bother writing a C program at all; it sounds like you want to build a script...

Comment: @trojanfoe :) Well i can always do it with a script but that doesn't answer my question? My requirement poses a constraint and I cannot use shell script to do so .

Comment: Question the artificial constraint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regardless of the programming language, calling system shell should really be the last resort when nothing else works, because:

- It almost surely will not work under other operating system.
- The error handling is actually complex (you need to capture and parse the error stream). Frequently this is just not done and all errors are ignored.
- If you port such an application to another platform, all called tools must be ported as well.

The same `wget` was a problem for us when we were porting some nasty perl code to mobile device. While just from Linux to Linux, we discovered that "standard" `wget` has some switches BusyBox does not support so needed to port `wget` as well, and later even `grep` as if perl would not have its own pattern search. After that I am fully convinced that better no.

Comment: Well the system() function was included in the standard library as a way to call the OS in a system-independant way. System() is the *only portable way* of calling the system. The contents of the string argument are of course system-dependant, but the system() libray function is not.

Comment: An unfortunate effect of using `system()` that shell will be call to parse command hence a shell is invoked along with the requested program. nice answered Audrius!..